# Alternatives for Mac OS X Aggregate Device on Linux and Windows

Tags: windows, linux, mac, audio, sound-card

In Mac OS X I am able to create an aggregate audio device, select, which hardware it will use to output/input sound, and, which sound channels it will use for output.

The utility to do this is located in *Applications/Utilities/Audio MIDI Setup*.

This is how the dialog looks:

[image]

Channel mapping:

[image]

I am looking for an alternative solution on Windows and Linux. A feature I am looking for in particular is to be able to choose, which output channels of my sound card I want to use for this virtual device.

The sound card I am using is M-Audio ProFire 610. The best solution would be opensource/freeware and handling both OSs, but I am looking for any tips and help for that, so feel free to chip in.

Comment: Where is this dialog in OS X?

Comment: It is under Applications/Utilities/Audio MIDI Setup

Answer (score 0):

Jack is supposed to support multiple components. Using multiple alsa_out ports, you can do a manual setup through a terminal. You can also use a Jack2 control device by configuring a setup file with your multiple alsa back-end devices and linking them to a single control device for Jack to consume. You will always need to check about your drivers for your hardware, but many pcm and Bluetooth capable items seem to be usable.

[How can I use multiple soundcards with JACK?](http://www.jackaudio.org/faq/multiple_devices.html)

[Linux Music Workflow: Switching from Mac OS X to Ubuntu with Kim Cascone](http://cdm.link/2009/08/linux-music-workflow-switching-from-mac-os-x-to-ubuntu-with-kim-cascone/)